# Unable to write table from multiple pages into collection in blueprism

Tags: collections, overwrite, blueprism

I'm extracting the data from a table that is spread across several web pages. I'm trying to fetch data per page and write into the same collection. For this I have given same collection in the output of these pages.

The problem is that the data instead of getting added is getting overwritten in the collection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's how it works! When you read the data into the collection then the previous data is being overwritten. That's the same as other data items :)

The solution is simple - read the data into temporary collection first.

Afterwards, use action:

```
object: Utility - Collection Manipulaiton
action: Append rows to collection
```

That will join the rows from your temporary one to the main one.

Comment: I tried this method before but the page I'm working has data spread across multiple pages. I want to extract these data into collection and collection data into excel.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you write it more precisely?